# 'Well' after: How to use 'well after' in a sentence?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, adverbs, modifiers

> She waited till well after midnight.

What does *well after* signify here? There are 51 definitions of *well* at the [Merriam Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well). It is not immediately obvious which one applies here.

Which part of speech should I be looking at? What part of speech is the word *well* in *well after*?

Lastly, can one say *It was well far*? If not, why not?

Comment: It's another way of saying "significantly later than".

Comment: why -2 for my question. Is my question dumb?!!

Comment: Given the closevoting reasons, it's because you didn't include prior research. At EL&U we usually require that you specify what attempts you made to find an answer to your question before posting, such as a google search for "well after".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question has not been well-received because you have not adhered to the guidance on [writing a good question](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: I've edited you Q to make it more suitable for EL&U. If you are unhappy about any of the edits, you can undo them by clicking on the 'edited' link above my name :)

Comment: used for emphasizing that a period of time or a distance is long
well after/before: Pete left the party well before you got there.
well ahead/behind: Paula finished the race well ahead of the other runners. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/well_1

Comment: @MετάEd How about *well away*? or *well down on last years takings*? And can we say *well far*?

Comment: @Araucaria "Well away" and "well down" I've seen and seem idiomatic (well away from shore; well down the list). "Well far" I've not seen and strikes me as awkward, not idiomatic, but I can't say why.

Comment: @MετάEd It's because this use of *well* is quite interesting and unusual because it's only used to modify prepositions (whereas *far* is an adjective/adverb). It falls into a small group of such words *right, dead, fresh* and a few others. They all look like adjectives - and it could be argued that they *are* in fact specialised adjectives (see my post below). But most dictionaries list them as adverbs. So the question is kind of inadvertently interesting :)

Comment: @MετάEd And actually *far* is quite unusual in itself, because it may well be a member of that group of 'adjectives' too .... "Far beyond the horizon" etc

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to tell for certain which part of speech this usage of the *well* represents. If you search very hard in dictionaries, you may be able to find the correct definition of this word listed under its use as an adverb. However, what these dictionaries will not tell you is that this meaning of the word *well*, meaning something like *to a considerable degree*, is grammatically very limited. In particular, we use it almost exclusively to modify prepositions or preposition phrases in standard English:

- well beyond its sell by date
- well after midnight
- well before the deadline
- well inside the line
- well outside of the terms and conditions

This 'adverb ' *well* is part of a family of other adverbs such as *straight*, *right*, *fresh*, *long*, *dead* and so forth that are used with special meanings to modify prepositions. Although their usage is very common, their meaning when used to modify prepositions is quite different to their meaning in other environments. The other thing about them is that they all look very much like adjectives and not adverbs at all. There is very little evidence, as far as I can ascertain, to make us think that they actually *are* adverbs—as opposed to adjectives—at all.

Here are some more examples:

- fresh **out** of college
- right **over** the net
- straight **after** the concert
- long **before** the second world war
- dead **on** time

We cannot use them like normal adverbs in standard English at all, although they are indeed used that way in some regional Englishes. For example we cannot use them to modify adjectives. The following are all ungrammatical in standard English, but fine in some regional varieties:

- It was well good.
- It's right hot in here.
- She's dead brilliant.

---

If you scroll down past *well* as a verb, noun and adjective at the [Merriam Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well) you will find the adverb *well*. If you scroll down further to the fifteenth definition thereunder, you will find the following definition:

> 15
>   :  to a large extent or degree :  considerably, far < *well over a million* >

This is the meaning in the Original Poster's example, where *well after midnight* means something similar to *long after midnight*.

What the dictionary will not tell you, however, is that interestingly, this meaning of the word *well* is confined in standard English almost entirely to the modification of prepositions.